# Unity does not detect onTrigger Event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in unity and I have two objects that I want to collide and then a trigger to be enabled. 
The one item I want my moving item to collide with has the tag "Boost".
Here is my code :

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Boost")
    {
        print("Boost here!");
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
     }
}
```

I notice that "Boost here!" is never printed.
Well here is my moving object info :
[image: Moving Object Info]

And here is the other object I want it to collide with:
[image: Second Object]

Comment: Have you tried putting a debugger and inspecting the tag property?

Comment: There are several questions on this, have you checked any of them to ensure your objects are setup correctly to receive the trigger event? aka atleast one object has a rigidbody?

Comment: @Eddge Yes both have rigidbodies as shown in the screenshots I've attached...

Comment: @MariaKodel it's better to post them in your question, instead of linking to them.  I cannot access them where I am at.

Comment: @Minh It doesn't seem to detect the tag for some reason

Comment: Based on your screenshot, that should work. Can you put `print("Trigger");` inside the `OnTriggerEnter` not inside the `if` statement and see if that's being called. Also, which script did you put the `OnTriggerEnter` insdie? Finally, how do you move your character? Post the code

Comment: Well now I am on my home PC, try removing the sphere collider from your object.  The Character Controller has a collider of its own.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `if` statement and when it hits, inspect the value of the `tag` property.  What does it say?

Comment: Maybe the colliders are just too small and they are not actually entering each other. Size 1 is pretty small. I would think that while testing this you would make the trigger size 100 or some other guaranteed to enter size.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper That's a possibility and I've seen similar issue here but since OP is no longer replying to comments, I think the problem is probably fixed.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper I'll try changing the scales. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

"If isKinematic is enabled, Forces, collisions or joints will not affect the rigidbody anymore. "

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html

Your second object is kinematic.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This statement applies to collison only(OnCollisionEnter). OP is using trigger(OnTriggerEnter) and isKinematic shouldn't matter. Scroll to the end of the collision [matrix table](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) to see that.

Comment: If I'm reading the question correctly, isn't Collision being used to trigger ONTriggerEnter?

Comment: @DontThinkJustGo Collision and trigger requires different configuration settings in order for their callback functions to be called. If those requirements are not met then it won't be called so no is likely the answer to that.